# converting data from sqlite PHP

Tags: javascript, php, sqlite, leaflet, heatmap

I have a number of coordinates stored in a sqlite database. I need these coordinates to be used in a heatmap on leaflet.
I'm using the following plugin: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.heat

The data needs to be in the following format:

```
var addressPoints = [
[52.344161, 4.912279],
[52.342425, 4.913038],
[52.342034, 4.913256],
[52.341987, 4.912462]];
```

I extract the data from the sqlite database in PHP using:

```
$db = new SQLite3('jwtrack.sqlite');
$results = $db->query("SELECT coord FROM trackjw");
while ($row = $results->fetchArray()) {
echo json_encode($row['coord']);
}
$db->close();
```

The data retrieved looks like:

```
"52.344161000, 4.912279000""52.342425000, 4.913038200""52.342034000, 4.913256000""52.341987000, 4.912462000""52.342336000, 4.912106000"
```

How can I get the SQLite data inserted in  'var addressPoints' in a correct manner?

Thansk in advance,

JWB

Comment: What is the column type of `coord` in your SQLite DB?

Answer (score 0):

If the data follows that same format with the quotes at start and end and double quotes in between pairs the following should produce an array with the pair as an entry.

```
$data='"52.344161000, 4.912279000""52.342425000, 4.913038200""52.342034000, 4.913256000""52.341987000, 4.912462000""52.342336000, 4.912106000"';

$pairs=explode('""',trim($data,'"'));
print_r($pairs);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 52.344161000, 4.912279000
    [1] => 52.342425000, 4.913038200
    [2] => 52.342034000, 4.913256000
    [3] => 52.341987000, 4.912462000
    [4] => 52.342336000, 4.912106000
)
```

You could alter your initial php however which would produce different data

```
$db = new SQLite3('jwtrack.sqlite');
$results = $db->query("SELECT coord FROM trackjw");
$json=array();

while( $row = $results->fetchArray() ) {
    $json[]=$row['coord'];
}
$db->close();
$json=json_encode( $json );
echo $json;
```

if you needed this without the quotes around the values...

```
$json=str_replace('"','',$json);
```

in the javascript then you could do:

```
echo "var addressPoints={$json};";
```

Comment: Thanks. That pointed me in the right direction. Ik have it working now.

Comment: Hi, I have been playing with it and when using it all in one PHP file it works great using var addressPoints = <?php echo "[{$json}]";?>;